# Having a test subdomain and a wildcard domain on SSL

Tags: ssl, virtualhost

I have SSL installed on my server, and I am using subdomain wildcards in the VirtualHost part of my ssl.conf file. The SSL certificate is valid for all subdomains, this works great.

Now i want to set up a subdomain and use this as a test, i.e. test.mywebapp.com. This test subdomain should point to a different document root. I want to put that in my ssl.conf by adding a new VirtualHost entry.

Currently the only entry is _default_:443. How can I add a new entry without overlapping with the exiting one? I tried test.mywebapp.com:443, but it keeps using the _default_ one.

Cheers,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

Keep `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` (or `*:443` or `the.ip.address:443`, but not the host name).

Use the `ServerName` directive within the virtual host to configure a different host.

Comment: Thanks, but can I add 2 servernames within a single virtualhost? I need to define a DocumentRoot for the test servername, and a DocumentRoot for the wildcard domain.

Comment: If you want two distinct DocumentRoots, you need to you two VirtualHost definitions (both can be for the same IP address).

Comment: That's what I thought, but then I can only create one single \_default_:*443 entry

Comment: You probably don't need `_default_:443` but `*:443`, see first example here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html